# Redirect outbound traffic on LAN going to port 443 to port 80 or 8080 instead

Tags: iptables, http, https

How would I achieve this, I've tried using iptables a bit but have had no success at all. Any help at all would be appreciated.

I basically just want it so that whenever a user on my LAN attempts to connect to a website with https (port 443) they are instead switched to http (port 80).

Separate question. Do some websites not allow http connections? Like google or youtube etc.

*Update* There is a specific website I want to use http and it does allow http connections if I force it in the URL. However I want all users who connect to it to connect through http instead by default.

-Thanks

Comment: Some websites either do not allow http connections or will redirect http connections to https immediately. Putting in an https to http redirect at the outgoing border of your LAN might cause problems for your network because of this.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Just a reminder that separate questions should be /separate/ questions, so that answers can be neatly and clearly tied to their questions.

Comment: Yeah but it was just a small question that i thought of while writing up question. Didn't think it deserved its on question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: you cannot. [1]

The reason is simple: if the user tells his browsers to connect to a site using `https`, the browser will start an `https` connection not an `http` one.

This incompatibility between `http` and `https` is the result of fundamental technical differences in the protocols. No workaround to "downgrade" from `https` to `http` has been developed when created for obvious security and privacy reasons. And now, technical differences make it totally impossible even to try.

And just for you to know: ports (i.e. the doors) have nothing to do with `http` and `https` (i.e. the protocol). So going to port 80 does not mean that your connection is gonna be in cleartext (`http`), that's actually the problem for what you are trying to do.

---

Just as an extra piece of info: what you attempt to do is illegal in many countries (at least if your users are not clearly warned beforehand [i.e. if they sign something proving they knew]).

---

[1] Well, you *can* redirect outbound to-443 traffic to port 80 instead. Technically, that's not hard at all. But that won't make an `https` request suddenly fall back to a clear text `http` request.